# (Django tutorial) importing 'views' from 'polls' app - syntax error PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Is it incorrect to use:

```
from [app name] import views
```

when you're inside that app?

I'm following the tutorial from the Django documentation website; and everything is working; however, I'm getting a syntax error (it still works though) every time I do the following:

[image]

*I'm using PyCharm

Comment: How about `from projectname.appname import module` or just `import module`?

Comment: You might have to setup your pycharm ide for the django project: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/django_guide.html

Comment: @PauloScardine - It is just the IDe that is showing errors for the OP. I guess its Not issues with running the program. The IDE does not have the project folder setup in the path.

Comment: Use relative imports for better scalability:
`from . import views`

Comment: @karthikr: I know, I was trying to guess Pycharm and Django versions based on the tests.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @kirelagin: really there's no error; only the (semi-annoying) red underline :) - trying what @Paulo suggested didn't work; but trying what @Mounir suggested (`from . import views`) worked.

Comment: hover over the red line it will say something.

Comment: @GlynJackson: it says `unresolved reference...`

Comment: try try import views on its own what happens? maybe an issue with the IDE

Comment: That's purely a PyCharm issue. I don't think I can help you with that (never used PyCharm), but I've seen suggestions to mark a directory as a source root somewhere in the project settings. In your case `mysite` is the root.

Comment: Is it bad programming practice to do `from . import views` or just `import views`? Because both of them work just fine!

Comment: @RoronoaZoro I can't say it's bad, but you shouldn't do this just because your IDE is dumb. By the way, it seems to be that the latter won't work in production.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you right click the `mysite.com/mysite` folder and select `Mark Directory As -> Source Root` you should be able to do `from polls import views`