# Cannot import my application in url.py file in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am completely new in Django and currently learning it from Udemy course.

First, I created my Django project and then created my application. I have inserted my application on settings.py in INSTALLED_APPS of project folder and then re run the the server as well.

Now, I have created a view in my application folder and want to use that in url.py of project folder. I could not able to import it as its showing that package not found.

Please see my program structure below:

[image: File structure]

I have written the code on pycharm IDE. My code in url.py is below

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from firstApp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('^$', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: See this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012558/django-tutorial-importing-views-from-polls-app-syntax-error-pycharm/17013408

Comment: The link from @FaroukT. should help you configure PyCharm correctly. The next problem is that `path()` shouldn't use `'^$` - you should use `path('', ...)` or `re_path(r'^$', ...)` instead. If your tutorial is using `url(r'^$', ...)` then it's probably written for an older Django version. I would think about looking for a more up-to-date guide, otherwise you might hit other issues where the code is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `path('^$', views.index, name='index')` to  `path('^$', include('firstApp.urls'), namespace='index')`
And you need to import include from django.urls